Get result in Karavan, get status: 500 Internal Server Error in Postman, why?
There is no error in Camel Karavan Apache when I post using Postman but why do I get status 500? And, the API through Kafka first to go to another route.
Well, I tried a lot of ways to make it appear in Postman when posting the body request, but I still cannot do this. I expect that the same result as in Karavan's log appear.
Yaml for Camel Karavan:
- restConfiguration:
    component: platform-http
    host: 5.181.132.121
    port: "8893"
    useXForwardHeaders: false
    contextPath: /api/v1
    apiContextPath: /api-doc
    bindingMode: auto
    inlineRoutes: true
- rest:
    id: rest-4e3a
    description: Insurance Claim Submission
    path: /claim-submission
    consumes: application/json
    produces: application/json
    bindingMode: auto
    post:
      - id: post-6804
        to: direct:direct-store-kafka
        consumes: application/json
        produces: application/json
        param:
          - description: Claim Type
            name: Claim-Type
            type: header
            dataType: String
- rest:
    id: rest-e831
    description: Insurance Claim Submission 1
    path: /claim-submission-1
    consumes: application/json
    produces: application/json
    get:
      - id: get-9e1e
        to: direct:test-direct
        consumes: application/json
        produces: application/json
- route:
    id: direct-store-kafka
    description: Store to Kafka
    from:
      id: from-d33b
      uri: direct
      parameters:
        name: direct-store-kafka
      steps:
        - log:
            id: log-59e6
            message: ${headers}
            logName: beginZaHeaders
        - choice:
            id: choice-9c6f
            when:
              - id: when-74fa
                expression:
                  simple:
                    id: simple-c3c2
                    expression: ${header.Claim-Type} == 'outpatient'
                steps:
                  - setHeader:
                      id: setHeader-350b
                      name: kafka.KEY
                      expression:
                        simple:
                          id: simple-850c
                          expression: ${uuid}
                  - log:
                      id: log-6462
                      message: ${header.kafka.KEY}
                      logName: key
                  - marshal:
                      id: marshal-d205
                      json:
                        id: json-ae81
                  - log:
                      id: log-5f65
                      message: ${body}
                  - to:
                      id: to-7424
                      uri: kafka
                      parameters:
                        topic: outpatient
                        brokers: kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092
            otherwise:
              id: otherwise-93fe
              steps:
                - log:
                    id: log-0c46
                    message: ${body}
- route:
    id: route-e9dc
    nodePrefixId: route-60b
    from:
      id: from-7c87
      uri: kafka
      parameters:
        topic: outpatient
        brokers: kafka-0:9092,kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092
      steps:
        - log:
            id: log-9197
            message: ${headers}
            logName: afterKafka
        - log:
            id: log-raw
            message: "Raw message: ${body}"
            logName: raw
        - setProperty:
            id: setProperty-8b6c
            name: bodyRequest
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-5a9b
                expression: ${body}
        - unmarshal:
            id: unmarshal-1181
            json:
              id: json-1a26
        - setProperty:
            id: setProperty-ff4c
            name: eventCoding
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-51be
                expression: ${body[entry][0][resource][eventCoding][code]}
        - log:
            id: log-c44e
            message: ${exchangeProperty.eventCoding}
            logName: eventCoding
        - setProperty:
            id: setProperty-56c5
            name: destination
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-f78b
                expression: >-
                  ${body[entry][0][resource][destination][0][receiver][identifier][type][coding][0][code]}
        - log:
            id: log-7e32
            message: ${exchangeProperty.destination}
            logName: destination code
        - log:
            id: log-a01e
            message: ${body}
            logName: bodyb4request
        - log:
            id: log-43d6
            message: ${headers}
            logName: headerDaTo?!
        - toD:
            id: toD-5fcd
            uri: >-
              https://veinscdr.mhnexus.com/baseR4/Endpoint?name=veinsBridge&organization=${exchangeProperty.destination}
        - log:
            id: log-b85f
            message: ${body}
            logName: bodyafterrequest
        - unmarshal:
            id: unmarshal-ef6a
            json:
              id: json-1123
        - log:
            id: log-9878
            message: ${body[entry][0][resource][address]}
            logName: endpointRequest
        - setBody:
            id: setBody-01bb
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-6be8
                expression: ${exchangeProperty.bodyRequest}
        - log:
            id: log-5931
            message: ${body}
            logName: requestBody
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-994c
            name: Content-Type
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-46da
                expression: application/json
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-5a5c
            name: CamelHttpMethod
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-cc51
                expression: POST
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-d934
            name: Accept
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-f1ff
                expression: application/json
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-1cea
            name: Accept-Encoding
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-4f3c
                expression: gzip
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-a462
            name: Claim-Type
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-8d10
                expression: outpatient
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-60e2
            name: Postman-Token
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-ab50
                expression: e3109c8d-6f83-43de-a1d1-6801658f7e7d
        - setHeader:
            id: setHeader-105f
            description: Token
            name: Authorization
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-0b03
                expression: >-
                  Bearer
                  hDkixqnIV2YgTeFG1lCBEO6+uAXUvx7bq7wg1FThAyslKtMtOvVScU315rvEblv5XkC9NNHKBhqn8aV/NbWt9qotI3b0Qgc7PVSfDu0Q/YnNk8eL0HX82ES1cN63hAMd
        - log:
            id: log-38b3
            message: ${headers}
            logName: headerOn!!
        - toD:
            id: toD-6b4d
            uri: http://5.181.132.121:8890/${exchangeProperty.eventCoding}
        - log:
            id: log-8d3f
            message: ${headers}
            logName: headOff!?
        - log:
            id: log-212c
            message: ${body}
            logName: medilik-request-log
        - setVariable:
            id: setVariable-a582
            name: global:getBody
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-2767
                expression: ${body}
- route:
    id: route-5e85
    nodePrefixId: route-638
    from:
      id: from-0e13
      uri: direct
      parameters:
        name: test-direct
      steps:
        - setProperty:
            id: setProperty-0a62
            name: setBody
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-19d2
                expression: ${variable:global:getBody}
        - setBody:
            id: setBody-0fe1
            expression:
              simple:
                id: simple-b31f
                expression: ${exchangeProperty.setBody}
        - log:
            id: log-754a
            message: ${headers}
            logName: headPush!!!
        - log:
            id: log-2e89
            message: ${body}
            logName: logXross

Output in Camel Karavan
Output in Postman
Let's say that I use GetAccessToken API request body in Postman and post it, toD with URI,http://5.181.132.121:8890/${exchangeProperty.eventCoding} will become http://5.181.132.121:8890/GetAccessToken and send the same request to the URI and should get this in Postman:
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "bundle-req-0001",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-20T11:15:33+10:00",
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:267b18ce-3d37-4581-9baa-6fada338038b",
            "resource": {
                "eventCoding": {
                    "system": "http://example.org/fhir/message-events",
                    "code": "GetAccessToken"
                },
                "destination": [
                    {
                        "name": "Get Access Token",
                        "endpoint": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi/api/clinic/GetAccessToken"
                    }
                ],
                "source": {
                    "endpoint": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi/api/clinic/GetAccessToken"
                },
                "reason": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/message-reasons-encounter",
                            "code": "getAccessToken"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "reference": "http://acme.com/ehr/fhir/Parameter/req-para-001"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:03f9aa7d-b395-47b9-84e0-053678b6e4e3",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
                "id": "03f9aa7d-b395-47b9-84e0-053678b6e4e3",
                "issue": [
                    {
                        "severity": "information",
                        "code": "informational",
                        "details": {
                            "text": ""
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://acme.com/ehr/fhir/Parameter/req-para-001",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Parameter",
                "id": "req-para-001",
                "parameter": [
                    {
                        "name": "responseParam",
                        "part": [
                            {
                                "name": "token",
                                "valueString": "hDkixqnIV2YgTeFG1lCBEKmzzowMimMP0PNPCIfVonpjvsAiItVcaEJK6Svylyjy2qBDlgUlTFMEQq12mKa5rD5LWoC2kwzx1RK3kZLjEETJwTBr06IoYC8QKfBwnNvE",
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "TokenExpiry",
                                "valueString": "5 Minutes"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Token_endpoint",
                                "valueString": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi/api/clinic/GetAccessToken"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Issuer",
                                "valueString": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Token_type",
                                "valueString": "Bearer"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

And, this is the body request:
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "bundle-req-0001",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-20T11:15:33+10:00",
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:267b18ce-3d37-4581-9baa-6fada338038b",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "MessageHeader",
                "eventCoding": {
                    "system": "http://example.org/fhir/message-events",
                    "code": "GetAccessToken"
                },
                "destination": [
                    {
                        "name": "Get Access Token",
                        "endpoint": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi/api/clinic/GetAccessToken"
                    }
                ],
                "source": {
                    "endpoint": "https://medilinkuat.medibridgeasia.tech/EccsProviderApi/api/clinic/GetAccessToken"
                },
                "reason": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/message-reasons-encounter",
                            "code": "getAccessToken"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "reference": "http://acme.com/ehr/fhir/Parameter/req-para-001"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://acme.com/ehr/fhir/Parameter/req-para-001",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Parameter",
                "id": "req-para-001",
                "parameter": [
                    {
                        "name": "requestParam",
                        "part": [
                            {
                                "name": "pstUsrID",
                                "valueString": "STtuKs2LoZtR9KpaqI5DxQ=="
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "pstPassword",
                                "valueString": "vTFhyoo1EMMy/gZn29b3OA=="
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "pstProvidercode",
                                "valueString": "GPSEL1334"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "pstAppID",
                                "valueString": "nPc6+IrS8o4gDX5ISFkEsOxW/9uJvLzY/LMMi2gOi4I="
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

the Camel Karavan Apache that I created supposedly to use the ToD to get through http://5.181.132.121:8890/${exchangeProperty.eventCoding}, so I get the same result when I post the body request to http://5.181.132.121:8890/${exchangeProperty.eventCoding}
For the logs, the body log has the same body like the result body, and for the headers log:
{
 Accept=application/json, 
 Accept-Encoding=gzip, 
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers=accept, content-type, 
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, 
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers=date, 
 Authorization=Bearer hDkixqnIV2YgTeFG1lCBEO6+uAXUvx7bq7wg1FThAyslKtMtOvVScU315rvEblv5XkC9NNHKBhqn8aV/NbWt9qotI3b0Qgc7PVSfDu0Q/YnNk8eL0HX82ES1cN63hAMd, 
 CamelHttpMethod=POST, 
 CamelHttpResponseCode=200, 
 CamelHttpResponseText=OK, 
 CamelMessageTimestamp=1717638824585, 
 Claim-Type=outpatient, 
 Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, 
 Expires=-1, 
 kafka.HEADERS=[
  RecordHeader(key = Accept, value = [42, 47, 42]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Accept-Encoding, value = [103, 122, 105, 112, 44, 32, 100, 101, 102, 108, 97, 116, 101, 44, 32, 98, 114]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Cache-Control, value = [110, 111, 45, 99, 97, 99, 104, 101]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Claim-Type, value = [111, 117, 116, 112, 97, 116, 105, 101, 110, 116]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Connection, value = [107, 101, 101, 112, 45, 97, 108, 105, 118, 101]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Content-Length, value = [51, 49, 55, 53]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Content-Type, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Host, value = [108, 111, 99, 97, 108, 104, 111, 115, 116, 58, 56, 50, 56, 56]), 
  RecordHeader(key = Postman-Token, value = [97, 101, 101, 102, 98, 52, 51, 102, 45, 51, 49, 55, 101, 45, 52, 48, 55, 97, 45, 56, 52, 48, 55, 45, 102, 57, 51, 57, 57, 56, 101, 51, 49, 56, 97, 49]), 
  RecordHeader(key = User-Agent, value = [80, 111, 115, 116, 109, 97, 110, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 47, 55, 46, 51, 55, 46, 51])
 ], 
 kafka.KEY=0F44D5203DE7BBC-0000000000000000, 
 kafka.OFFSET=362, 
 kafka.PARTITION=0, 
 kafka.TIMESTAMP=1717638824585, 
 kafka.TOPIC=outpatient, 
 Postman-Token=e3109c8d-6f83-43de-a1d1-6801658f7e7d, 
 transfer-encoding=chunked, 
 X-AspNet-Version=4.0.30319, 
 X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, 
 X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, 
 X-Powered-By=Smile CDR 2023.08.R04 FHIR REST Endpoint (FHIR Server; FHIR 4.0.1/R4; HAPI FHIR 6.8.3), 
 X-Request-ID=zffLNoep54wpVVsW, 
 X-UA-Compatible=IE=10, 
 X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
}


Can you explain better, what you expect. You use postman to call camel and you get a http 500 error back, and there is no "error message". Do you want to see some kind of Internal Service Error message that contains some kind of java stracktrace or what?
And do you see any such details in the Camel log (what you call karavan log)

just edited my question, the role of my Camel Karavan is supposedly to make it able to use the API from other Camel Karavan, and I expect that the Postman can get the same result as same as in Karavan(For some reason, Karavan has no error and give the result) with status 200

I just want to know why this happened...

and, I don't get any Java Stack Trace...
